# I get NullPointerException but my object is not null

Tags: android

At the beginning I had a perfectly working code; I was creating a 'location' and then I would save it in a database and retrieve it any time I wanted. 'Location' was an object that only contained Strings. Then I wanted to add some icons that could desctribe the location easier and my program crashed.

I am getting an error:

```
2021-01-07 11:01:17.484 32731-32731/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner, PID: 32731
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner.model.LocationModel.getID()' on a null object reference
    at pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner.adapter.DBAdapter.deleteLocation(DBAdapter.java:414)
    at pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner.activity.Api.Synchronization.DownloadLocation.onPostExecute(DownloadLocation.java:123)
    at pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner.activity.Api.Synchronization.DownloadLocation.onPostExecute(DownloadLocation.java:33)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

But when I debugged my app I noticed that the object - product - is not null:

[image]

Code for DBAdapter.java:414:

```
        for(ProductModel product : mainProductList){
        if(product.getLocationModel().getID() == locationModel.getID()){
            Log.e(TAG, "moving productId: " + product.getId() + "; productApiId: " +
                    product.getApiID() + "; to defaultLocation");
            product.setLocationModel(defaultLocation);
            product.setLastEditDateTime();
        }
    }
```

Code for (DownloadLocation.java:123:

```
DBAdapter.getInstance(context).deleteLocation(location);
```

Before I added icons to the 'location' the code worked, I have not however changed the 'product' part of my code and I have no idea what might have changed

Comment: you have 169 items in your list, are you sure they all have values

Comment: yes, I'm sure, I haven't changed any of the products and before my 'upgrade' the code was working well. Products in the database are correct

Answer (score 0):

It's not the product which is being `null`.
It's the `LocationModel` associated with your product.

The method `getLocationModel()` returns `null` which is why you can't call the `getID` method and get the NPE.

You should insert a check if the LocationModel is not null before querying its ID. Something along these lines:

```
for(ProductModel product : mainProductList) {
    LocationModel model = product.getLocationModel();
    if (model != null && model.getID() == locationModel.getID()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "moving productId: " + product.getId() + "; productApiId: " +
                    product.getApiID() + "; to defaultLocation");
        product.setLocationModel(defaultLocation);
        product.setLastEditDateTime();
    }
}
```